# PHP calendar with recurring events

Tags: php, zend-framework, calendar

Does anyone know of open-source PHP calendar class that handles the storage, retrieving and removing of events.

I have looked everywhere and all I can find is classes that will create the HMTL output for a calendar but don't manage the actual calendar events.

I can't use google calendar as the project I am working on doesn't allow me to make the calendar publicly accessible and it also needs to work offline.

I know this question has been asked a thousand times before but I have never come across a complete answer.

UPDATE::
This calendar is going to be used in a commercial application but unfortunately we don't have the funding to buy software licensces at teh current time so all 3rd party scripts would need to be free to distribute in a commercial application

Thanks

Comment: Google Calendars can be made publicly available

Comment: Sorry I meant to say to I can't use Google calendar as the calendar I am working on isn't to be publicly visible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the project I'm working on currently, we've had a similar challenge. We also wanted to show events that aren't *per se* calendar items, but items that came out of action plans.

We've used [Full Calender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), combined with PHP programming that supplies the JSON feed. Full Calendar also supplies many event hooks, which in our case triggers a Ajax post to PHP Programming which edits the database.

A little more detailed:

We call Full Calendar with:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: '/pl_feed.php'
});
```

Full Calendar then visits, for instance:

```
/pl_feed.php?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646
```

(the extra parameter is used to prevent caching)

pl_feed.php generates the events that are displayed in the Calendar.

By the way: I found that the David Powers Date Class (read his book: it's good) is a joy to work with. You can download it at the site of the publisher: http://www.apress.com/9781430210115

When it's done generating the requested events, pl_feed.php puts them in a multi-dimensional array and echoes the array with json_encode:

```
    foreach ($array_events as $array_event) {

        $array_feed_item['id'] = $array_event['id'];
        $array_feed_item['title'] = //Whatever you like to be the title;
        $array_feed_item['start'] = $array_event['start']; //Y-m-d H:i:s format
        $array_feed_item['end'] = $array_event['end']; //Y-m-d H:i:s format
        $array_feed_item['allDay'] = 0;
        $array_feed_item['color'] = 'blue'; //Whatever you like, of course
        $array_feed_item['borderColor'] = 'blue';
        //You can also a CSS class: 
        $array_feed_item['className'] = 'pl_act_rood';

        //Add this event to the full list of events:
        $array_feed_items[] = $array_feed_item;
    }

    echo json_encode($array_feed_items);
```

Full Calendar will then show you the events generated by /pl_feed.php.

Comment: I am also looking to use FullCalendar but can't get recurring events working properly. Does the script you have accommodate this?

Comment: The JSON-feed I created with PHP generates the recurring events, not FullCalandar itself. And it's easy to give these events a little difference in appearance, so that it's clear to the user that it's a recurring event.

Comment: Is there any chance you could share the script you created?

Comment: Phew... The script is really tailored to the needs of our application. It gets predefined actions from Facility Management Management Plans, takes the last occurence, a predefined frequency and starts adding recurring events. Let me see if I can get some generic code for you.

Comment: Many thanks Rick, I think I am getting there now! P.S. I am actually reading that book at the minute!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

http://www.softcomplex.com/products/php_event_calendar/

or

http://www.easyphpcalendar.com/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you make your app simply work with a protocol like [CalDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV). Then you can simply let the users of your application supply their own calendaring storage. Some users may choose to use Google Calendar. Some users may have an existing Apple iCal server. Some users may set up their own server for this.

For completion (and to make it easy for new users to get started) you could include e.g. [DAViCal](http://www.davical.org/) (PHP, open source) as a default solution for those who do not have a calendaring service yet.

There are PHP libraries that let you easily connect to a CalDAV server such as [iCalCreator](http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php) and [iCal Maker](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3619-PHP-Generate-calendars-in-iCal-format.html)

Comment: I live the flexibility of this approach but it looks like DAViCal only works with PostgreSQL. Do you know of a mysql variant?

Comment: @James: DAViCal is busy moving to a PDO-based database access layer, which would allow MySQL, SQLite and other database backends. Perhaps you can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google gdata api to manage your events. It has great recurring events support.

They also have private events feature, which makes your events not visible to the public.  it's supported by the zend framework  as well - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment aporat but unfortunately google calendar is not an option for this project. Do you know of any other open source calendar libraries?